# Typed.js in more than one line

Tags: jquery

I am using typed.js plugin for typing effect. I have 2 lines, after the first line finishes, i want to start on second line. This is what i have tried, the issue is, when it switches to second line, briefly you can see 
 tag being typed. I dont want this. Please tell me what i am doing wrong. I also tried calling typed function in the callback of first but it didnt work :(

Below is the my code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typed.js"></script>
    <title>Typed.js</title>

<style>
   .test {
       font-size: 30px;
   }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="box1"></span>
    <span class="box2"></span>

<script>
  $(function(){

        $(".box1").typed({
            strings: ["First sentence.", "<p></p><span class='test'>Second sentence.</span>",""],
            typeSpeed: 0,
            showCursor: false,

        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but I realized you can add a `\n` to the string you want to display and style the typed element with `white-space: pre;` and voilà, it works without showing any tag.

So the Javascript code would be something like this:

```js
  $(function(){

        $(".box1").typed({
            strings: ["First sentence.", "\n<span class='test'>Second sentence.</span>",""],
            typeSpeed: 0,
            showCursor: false,

        });
    });
```

and the CSS would be:

```css
.box {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

It also works with one string only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding contentType attribute?

```
$(".box1").typed({
        strings: ["First sentence.", "<p></p><span class='test'>Second sentence.</span>",""],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        showCursor: false,
        contentType: 'html'
});
```

Comment: its by default html :-(